# Redefine methods in repository with spring-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using `spring-data-couchbase 2.1.2`, I want add methods to a single repository.
In implementation class:

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepositoryCustom { 

  @Autowired
  RepositoryOperationsMapping templateProvider; 
....
}
```

I added the `RepositoryOperationsMapping` but the object is not injected, I have the error below:

```
[org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.RepositoryOperationsMapping]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

For spring configuration I used the `spring.xml` file, how add in xml file the `RepositoryOperationsMapping` reference?

Thanks. Bye.

Comment: Could you please add the version of Spring Data Couchbase you are using?

Comment: The version is 2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, below a snippet my `spring.xml` file

```
<couchbase:clusterInfo login="${cluster.username}" password="${cluster.password}"  id="clusterInfo" />

    <couchbase:bucket bucketName="${bucket.name}" bucketPassword="${bucket.password}" id="bucket"/>

    <!-- template is just using default parameters and references as well -->
     <couchbase:template translation-service-ref="myCustomTranslationService" />
     <bean id="myCustomTranslationService" 
  class="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.translation.JacksonTranslationService"/>



   <bean id="couchbaseTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="clusterInfo"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="bucket" />
        <constructor-arg ref="myCustomTranslationService" />
   </bean> 

   <bean id="repositoryOperationsMapping" class="org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.RepositoryOperationsMapping"> 
     <constructor-arg ref="couchbaseTemplate"/> 
   </bean>
```